# How do you post as a bot with a different avatar image and name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

There is a discord bot called [Unbelivaboat](https://unbelievaboat.com/). It has a command called `!suggest <your suggestion>`. When someone suggests something, the bot copies their message and posts it on a different channel. However, nickname and the avatar image is changed (see picture below). How did the bot do this?

[image: Example]

When you click on the profile you get this only:

[image]

Comment: it is probably a webhook

Comment: The bot might also change its name and avatar, send that message, then change them back.

Answer (score 1):

The bots avatar can be canged using following code,

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

token = 'TOKEN HERE'
pfp_path = "path/to/file.png"

fp = open(pfp_path, 'rb')
pfp = fp.read()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.edit_profile(password=None, avatar=pfp)

client.run(token)
```

If you want a user to change the picture of a bot, you can give them the option to add their own path (for the picture), like here

```
import discord
from discord.exe import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')

@bot.command()
   async def profile(ctx, path):
   token = 'TOKEN HERE'
   pfp_path = "path"

   fp = open(pfp_path, 'rb')
   pfp = fp.read()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.edit_profile(password=None, avatar=pfp)

client.run(token)
```

With this setup, a user can run the command `;profile https://vlands.net/underconstruction.png` and it will apply the picture that is located at this adress.